# Initializing a 2D array

Tags: java, ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have the below Java code which I need to convert to Swift. First one is simply initializing a 2D array with a number of rows and columns.

```
double[][] VAR1 = new double[5][10];
```

Second one is initializing a 2D array with some initial values.

```
double[][] VAR2 = new double[][]{ {2.1, 4.3}, {5.4, 8.9},};
```

---

I can't figure out how to do the first one.

But I have a shot at the second one. Not sure if it's correct though.

```
var var2: [[Double]] = [[2.1], [4.3], [5.4], [8.9]]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898434/swift-3-2d-array-of-int for the first question.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! The syntax takes a bit of getting used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - should be like this:

```
var var2: [[Double]] = [[2.1, 4.3], [5.4, 8.9]]
```

And for the first one:

```
var var1: [[Double]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 10), count: 5)
```

Comment: Oh right! Thanks. I corrected the second one. For the first one though, 5 and 10 aren't values, they're to specify the _capacity_ I think. I just took the words rows and columns out of a similar Java [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12231453/1077789).

Comment: Ah, ok.  In that case, since you don't need to specify capacity in Swift, you could just say `var var1 = [[Double]]()`.  Adding the () at the end initializes an empty array of the specified type.

Comment: I see. But if we need to, is there a way to specify the capacity or it's simply impossible in Swift?

Comment: Yes, you can do that like this `var var1 = [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: Double(), count: 10), count: 5)`.  This creates a "2D" array (Swift people don't refer to them as such) with 5 "rows", with each row containing 10 "columns" of type `Double`.  I don't often see people doing this in Swift, but of course you are welcome to do so.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.