# Swift append to 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to append a value to a 2d array in Swift but it's throwing me an "index out of range" error on line 8

```
private var cards : [[Int]] = [[]]

init() {
    //Fill cards array by adding all cards
    for i in 0...12{
        for x in 0...3{
            cards[0].append(i+2)    //append card number... 2,3,4,5 etc
            cards[1].append(x)      //append card type... hearts, diamonds, clubs and spades
                                    //with a value which represents it (0, 1, 2 and 3)
        }
    }
}
```

[Swift code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cTvd.png)

Comment: maybe insed the secdon loop the single line of `cards.append([i+2, x])` would rather be a better approach in case of your array, but I am not sure that maches your expectations... however syntactically it is perfect.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898434/swift-3-2d-array-of-int.

Comment: In your case I'd suggest you to create a struct/class `Card` with `number: Int` and `type: String` properties. After that you can have only one array of cards with necessary data, easy extensible for new kind of properties in it. Just FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the inner arrays of `cards` using `cards[0]`, since you initialize `cards` as an empty array of arrays and hence `cards.count = 0`, so `cards[0]` does not exist.

```
private var cards = [[Int]]()

init() {
    //Fill cards array by adding all cards
    for i in 0...12{
        for x in 0...3{
            cards.append([i+2,x])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks! I'm confused as to why the append code on line 7 works fine but code on line 8 doesn't? both 0 and 1 have empty sizes.

Comment: I misunderstood your logic for the first time and hence the array dimensions were wrong in my first solution, check the updated answer. Btw storing card values like this is a really bad idea, you should create a `Card` struct and store a stack of cards as `[Card]`, not `[[Int]]`.